# Integration of Azure App Services with AD

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have four Azure AppServices which are complete independent applications. I want to provide a kind of a portal that aggregates those four. When a user logs in he sees all applications he has access to depending on his scope. From the portal he can navigate to the other applications and do the user management stuff like adding new users and grant access to a specific application.

[image]

Is the picture above a good pattern to do it?

If I would start from scratch, what would be a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

App services don't have access to different app's directories, so I do not think this is possible.

Your best bet might be to make a feature request to the product team on User Voice. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory